# How do I connect outlets of type id?

Tags: objective-c, iboutlet

BezierView.h of the Apple BezierPathLab example shows a list of outlets of type id:

```
// Outlets
id lineColorWell;
id fillColorWell;
id backgroundColorWell;
id lineWidthSlider;
id pathTypeMatrix;
id filledBox;
id angleSlider;
id capStyleMatrix;
id zoomSlider;
id lineTypeMatrix;
```

Interface Builder shows the connections are made but how is this done without IBOutlets?

Comment: What do you mean by: *"how is this done without IBOutlets"*?

Comment: If i use: IBOutlet id lineColorWell; i can make connections in IB.  If I disconnect the existing connection and don't change the code as above there is nothing to connect to.  How was it connected?

Comment: Actually I do not see the value of doing so. But from an academic point of view, it may well be that the connection was made to "IBOutlet id something" in IB and later the keyword "IBOutlet" was removed. And I guess that it would be possible to edit the XML version of the NIB file and create any connection that is virtually thinkable. (Both just guesses)

Comment: The possibility of either of those solutions being published in apple's samples is slim to none... Wouldn't you agree?  I'm thinking that it is more likely a legacy coding artifact that I never learned about... It that might have come about in the infancy of IB.